# CiviMail Template links are not working

Tags: civimail, message-templates

I am using CiviCRM on wordpress 4.8.1

I am trying to set up our email templates.
When I link to something the html is correct and links to the correct page, but when I send the email the links become 
https://mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=60&qid=

What is going on here?  How do I fix it?
Thank you.

****UPDATE****
I just discovered that even when trying to browse the server for an image in the template, I get redirected to a 404 page.   I hope that sheds some light on what the problem might be.

Comment: I want to add that I realize Civi generates a redirect link, but when we click these links we are getting a 404 error page.

Comment: What is the value of `qid` you set in templates? Is it a token? Can you paste the link you included in your template?

Comment: any chance you are jumping between http and https?

Comment: I don't know.  When I create the link in the template I select https, because we are using ssl.

Comment: No it is not a token. It is a regular html link.